# Qual é a diferença entre “mas” e “mais”?

Tags: significado, ortografia, uso-de-palavras

Qual é a diferença entre *mas* e *mais*?

Quais das frases abaixo estão corretas em relação ao contexto de *porém*?

> Ele é pequeno, mas é bonito
>
> Ele é pequeno, mais é bonito

Comment: Quando eu era supervisor dos transcritores de áudio, era muito comum erros desse tipo nos textos transcritos :)

Comment: Esta pergunta quase me matava de ataque cardíaco!

Comment: E ainda assim, ganhei -2 pela pergunta :\

Comment: E nenhum é meu porque sei bem que há muita gente que não sabe a diferença.

Comment: Acho que no dia-a-dia em português brasileiro é complicado distinguir o *mas* do *mais* somente pelo som, já que pelo som acaba se transformando o mas em mais em algumas regiões, então devemos considerar o contexto da conversa para saber o é dito.

Comment: Parece simples **mas** causa muito transtorno, **mais** muito transtorno mesmo!

Comment: @bCognusia esse segundo, em Portugal, seria comummente um «mas».

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Mais

É usado com o sentido de adição, aumento ou soma.

## Mas

É usado com sentido de oposição ou restrição

Comment: `Fiquei furioso, mas mesmo muito!` - não tem sentido de oposição ou restrição.

Comment: @ANeves tenho que concordar, irei revisar assim que possivel a resposta para torna-la mais correta ainda hoje

Comment: (Não acho que a resposta esteja errada. Apenas que pode ficar ainda melhor. :)

Answer (score 5):

Eu já trabalhei como revisor de textos durante um tempo e desenvolvi algumas técnicas pessoais para poder distinguir `mas` de `mais`.

Por exemplo, quando quero saber se é `mas` ou `mais` eu tento trocar a palavra por `porém`. Se tiver sentido, então é `mas`.

O `mais` tem, geralmente, o sentido de adição. Então creio que nesse caso dispensa substituições. Basta apenas lembrar se o sentido da palavra que representar uma adição ou não.

Exemplo:

> Ele é meu amigo, mas às vezes é chato. Vira e mexe eu saio **mais** ele.
>
> Ele é meu amigo, **porém** às vezes é chato. Vira e mexe eu saio **mais** ele.