# Conjuntos minimais de monossílabos formados só por "a" no português de Portugal

Tags: português-europeu, pronúncia

Uma palavra monossílaba pode ser tônica (com vogal regular) ou átona (com vogal reduzida): "*quê × que*"; "*dou × do*"; "dê × de"; "*sê × se*"; etc. Porém, no português brasileiro essa distinção não ocorre quando a vogal da palavra for "a". Ou seja, os pares "*dá × da*" e "*más × mas*" (ou "*mais × mas*"), embora distintos em Portugal (`/'da × də~dɐ/` e `/'maʃ × mɐʃ/` ou `/'majʃ × mɐjʃ/`), no Brasil eles são homófonos (o que acaba gerando [confusão](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-mas-e-mais)).

Existem quase uma dezena de palavras monossílabas compostas apenas pela vogal **a**. Exceto pelo acento agudo nalguns deles, não é óbvio quais são tônicos e quais não são no português de Portugal. A única certeza que tenho é a de que o artigo é átono, mas a preposição e a crase não me são claras pois já ouvi elas sendo pronunciadas de ambas as formas. Minha dúvida é esta: Nas variações não-brasileiras da língua, como estas palavras se agrupam em [conjuntos minimais de tonicidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair#Stress)? Quais são pronunciadas com a [vogal regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Open_central_unrounded_vowel.ogg) e quais são pronunciadas com a [vogal reduzida](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3AMid-central_vowel.ogg)?

- Artigo "*a*";
- Pronome "*a*" (uma das formas acusativas do pronome "ela");
- Preposição "*a*";
- Crase "*à*" (preposição+artigo);
- Interjeição "*ah*";
- Forma verbal "*há*";
- Nome de letra "*a*";
- Nome "*á*" (singular de "ás", asa).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em Portugal, a vogal é aberta quanda há acento (agudo ou grave) e na interjeição *ah* (nunca vi escrito só "a"). A letra também se lê com vogal aberta (como de resto todas as vogais). Nos outros casos, lê-se com vogal fechada.

Comment: Já ouvi a preposição sendo pronunciada tônica (*"Iremos **á** Madri"*) por várias vezes, em fala rápida e cantada. Foi isso tal que me motivou a fazer esta pergunta. A crase já ouvi nas duas formas.

Comment: @Seninha Em Portugal? Acho difícil. Tens exemplos?

Comment: @Seninha concordo com o Artefacto: podes ter ouvido "iremos á Maia", mas não "iremos á* Madrid" - aí ouvirias "iremos **a** Madrid".

Comment: @Artefacto. Foi na fala de alguns colegas de faculdade que moravam por aqui. Talvez o sotaque deles tenha se corrompido com o nosso durante a estadia e passaram a pronunciar a preposição e crase como tônicas para distinguir do artigo...

Comment: A preposição pronuncia-se fechada, mas _à_ aberta. Em _iremos a Madrid_ não há crase porque _Madrid_ não se usa com artigo (ao contrário da Maia, ou da Guarda).

Answer (score 1):

Os monossílabos átonos com A existentes no português são:

- a as ca da la ma na pa ta das las lha mas nas pra tas lhas

Para os quais se encontram as variantes tónicas não nasais:

- à às cà cá dá há lá má ná pá tá dás más prà tás