# Verbo “trazer”, nestas duas conjugações quais têm vogais abertas e fechadas?

Tags: verbos, pronúncia

Nos presentes do indicativo e subjuntivo do verbo ***trazer*** quais são as conjugações com vogal aberta e vogal fechada?

O verbo trazer é irregular portanto nas seguintes tabelas assinalei a sílaba tónica com itálico e a mudança de vogal na raiz com negrito. Também assinalei a separação silábica usando um ponto (não tenho a certeza se está correcto — por favor confiram).

O uso do termo ***"alternância vocálica"*** parece-me por vezes confuso na literatura, dependendo dos autores parece que pode referir-se a:

1. Mudança de vogal aberta para vogal fechada.
2. Mudança de consoante na raiz do verbo.

Mas neste caso quero colocar a pergunta abstraindo o termo ***"alternância vocálica"*** e procuro saber simplesmente:

1. Se ocorre mudança entre vogal aberta e vogal fechada na raiz?
2. Se há uma regra que podemos aplicar para detectar a mudança na vogal? Por exemplo encontrei [esta regra](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5055) que desconhecia e quero saber se também é válida para detectar a mudança entre vogal aberta e fechada neste verbo da 2ª conjugação?

| Pessoa | Presente do Indicativo | Sílaba tónica |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Eu | *tra*.**g**o | rizotónica |
| Tu | *tra*.zes | rizotónica |
| Ele | *traz* | rizotónica |
| Nós | tra.*ze*.mos | arrizotónica |
| Vós | tra.*zeis* | arrizotónica |
| Eles | *tra*.zem | rizotónica |

| Pessoa | Presente do Subjuntivo | Sílaba tónica |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Eu | *tra*.**g**a | rizotónica |
| Tu | *tra*.**g**as | rizotónica |
| Ele | *tra*.**g**a | rizotónica |
| Nós | tra.***g**a*.mos | arrizotónica |
| Vós | tra.***g**ais* | arrizotónica |
| Eles | *tra*.**g**am | rizotónica |

Comment: É tudo igual. Não há diferença nos a's.

Comment: Em Portugal, os aa tónicos são abertos; os átonos, *tr**a**zemos, tr**a**zeis*, são fechados, como em muitos outros verbos e outras palavras em geral.

Comment: @Jacinto estou agora a ver se consigo [ler isto](https://european-portuguese.info/pt/) para compreender melhor. Sinceramente só de ouvido dizendo as palavras a diferença para mim não é aparente. Há outros verbos como "recear" em que é perceptivel. Obrigado pela indicação.

Comment: @bad_coder Você está interessado prioritariamente na pronúncia em pt-PT?

Comment: @stafusa eu ainda estou a tentar perceber como isto funciona em pt-PT, mas as obras de referência que estou a usar são na maioria brasileiras e são escritas por referência à   obra de Mattoso da Câmara Jr. (portanto frequentmente não é clara a distinção e por vezes nem é preciso fazê-la). Por agora a resposta do Jacinto deixou-me inteirmante satisfeito, e também refere a diferença entre o português brasileiro e europeu. Se alguém sentir que mais há a acrescentar convido-os a responderem para complementar.

Comment: @stafusa e bad_coder, no Brasil também há alguma alternância vocálica, mas não no *a* aberto vs fechado (é sempre aberto) e muito menos pronunciada. Nos verbos, e creio que em muitas outras palavras, o *e* e *o* são fechados quando átonos, mas podem ser abertos quando tónicos (*e* aberto em *resta* mas fechado em *restamos* (*ê*, só que átono); em Portugal, aberto vs. *r[ɨ]stamos*). Depois há a alternância vocálica que até se representa graficamente, que é universal: *visto - veste, subo - sobe*. Mas creio que isto já ia muito além da pergunta...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Portugal, como eu falo e como sempre ouvi falar, esse *a* é fechado quando é átono (1ª e 2ª pessoa do plural) e é aberto quando é tónico (restantes pessoas). Isto é válido não só de *trazer* mas da maioria dos verbos e outras palavras em geral. Isso mesmo afirma a *Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014, p. 520), que também confirma o que o Schilive disse nos comentários: que no Brazil esse *a* é sempre aberto.

Vou exemplificar (a pronúncia de Portugal), usando [ɐ] para representar o *a* fechado e [a] para o aberto (são os símbolos do alfabeto fonético internacional):

> infinitivo        eu            tu             ele              nós                vós               eles
> (fechado)                                                            (fechados)
> tr[**ɐ**]zer:      tr[**a**]go      tr[**a**]zes      tr[**a**]z          tr[**ɐ**]zemos      tr[**ɐ**]zeis      tr[**a**]zem
> l[**ɐ**]var:        l[**a**]vo       l[**a**]vas       l[**a**]va        l[**ɐ**]vamos       l[**ɐ**]vais      l[**a**]vam
> p[**ɐ**]tir:       p[**a**]rto     p[**a**]rtes     p[**a**]rte     p[**ɐ**]rtimos      p[**ɐ**]rtis      p[**a**]rtem

Naturalmente, o *a* também fechado nas formas arrizotónicas de outros tempos. Por exemplo no indicativo de *trazer*, todas as pessoas do imperfeito, futuro, etc. — *tr*[ɐ]*zia, tr*[ɐ]*rei*... E a mesma coisa acontece noutras palavras:

> c[**a**]r[**ɐ**], c[**ɐ**]rinh[**ɐ**], c[**ɐ**]rinho, c[**ɐ**]ríssimo
> /b**ɐ**t**a**t**ɐ**, b**ɐ**t**ɐ**t**a**d**ɐ**/

Isto é o fenómeno geral da redução do *a* átono no português europeu. Só se aplica ao *a* oral (o nasal é fechado mesmo quando tónico, *c**an**to, ac**am**po*) e monotongo (o *a* é aberto nos ditongos mesmo quando átono, *c**au**samos, p**ai**ramos*). Mesmo nos orais monotongos há mais exceções. O *a* é aberto mesmo que átono quando forma sílaba com um l a seguir (*s**a**ltamos*); e é fechado mesmo que tónico quando seguido de consoante nasal ([**ɐ**]*mo,* *ab*[**ɐ**]*no, ap*[**ɐ**]*nho*); exceção a esta exceção é o *a* aberto em *g*[**a**]*nhar, g*[**a**]*nho, g*[**a**]*nhamos*, etc. (ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5738/porque-%C3%A9-que-no-meu-sotaque-ganho-n%C3%A3o-rima-com-banho)) e na primeira pessoa do plural do pretérito do indicativo dos verbos em *-ar* (*lev*[**a**]*mos*, por oposição a *lev*[**ɐ**]*mos* no presente).

Nos verbos este padrão é quase universal. Nas palavras de outras classes há mais exceções. Por exemplo, o *a* tónico do radical mantém-se aberto quando passa a átono nos advérbios em -*mente* (*f**a**cilmente, r**a**ramente*), nos diminutivos em -*zinho* (*devag*[**a**]*rzinho*), mas não nos em *-inho* (*devag*[**ɐ**]*rinho*). Mantém-se aberto mesmo que átono em palavras como *contr*[**a**]*ção*. Nalgumas desta palavras o *a* era na grafia pré AO90 seguido de consoante muda (*contracção*), mas noutras não era—*infl*[**a**]*ção* nunca teve consoante muda.

Há o fenómeno paralelo da elisão do *e* átono ou a sua redução a /ɨ/ (som quase inaudível que não existe no português brasileiro, comparem [g**e**lar](https://forvo.com/word/gelar/#ca) pronunciado por portuguesa e brasileiros; *v[ɛ]lo*, com *e* aberto, mas *v[ɨ]lamos* ou *vlamos*) e da redução do *o* átono a [u] (*g[ɔ]sto*, com *o* aberto, mas *g[u]stamos*). Nos verbos isto acontece, tal como em *trazer*, na 1ª e 2ª pessoa do plural do presente do indicativo e subjuntivo. Novamente, em Portugal mas não no Brasil. Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra explicam isto exaustivamente (p. 519-28).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Jacinto vou estar a ver isto nos próximos dias! Depois do teu comentário inicial voltei a dizer o verbo e já conseguia ouvir a diferença, agora vou tentar perceber a teoria e aprofundar.

Comment: @bad_coder, sempre às ordens. Acrescentei mais uma achega e uma referência que explica isto exaustivamente.